# How to have my canvas (fabricjs) always be full width of the window, also after resizing window and keep objects in place

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas with an image that fills the canvas. This works fine but I would like to have the canvas be full width of the window. At the moment the canvas is the width of the image I put in it.

I've tried the following at the bottom of my script:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.setHeight(img.height);
  canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  canvas.renderAll();
}

resizeCanvas();
```

But this does not work.

I've also tried giving the canvas element 100% width in its paramaters and with css, both with no success.

Codepen with working example:

https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/YzpeEEr

If you increase your screen size the image stops after a while instead of keeping full width of the browser window.

Is this possible? With keeping all objects in their place?

Comment: Please provide a working example here on Stack Overflow. You can do so with Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar). At the very least, provide enough code to reproduce the issue in the question itself, here on Stack Overflow, not just on CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not easy to fix but i found some documentation that could make it work.

First edit the code to `realWidth` and add `var realWidth = window.innerWidth;`

and then for setting the background remove your current code and add

```
  fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 10;
  fabric.Image.fromURL(source, function(img) {
      img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
```

this should fix the problem, and the backgound will take the full size of the screen.

Update for the new calculation of the circle position.

is equal to `Newposition= oldPosition * (newWidth / oldWidth)`

Here you can see that it work https://codepen.io/AlenToma/pen/ExNEooX

Comment: Thank you but the objects are on another spot over the image when resizing. Is it possible to have them on the same spot? So the dot on the chair, stays on the chair etc.

Comment: That is what you have to do, you need to clear all the canvas and rebuild it. so the dot can follow the image resizing. if you are not able to do that then you could tell so i could do it for you. but it should be easy for you to handle that on your own.

Comment: nevermind i did fix this for you now. the circle will follow the rezise image. have a look at codepen agen. and let me know if you need anything else. also make sure to read my update so you could understand.

Comment: @twan if my answer did solve your problem do not forget to give the point :) it took to much of my time to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer. Maybe you also know how to resize the image width and height according to the scale? I have this codepen example: https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/bGBvzZR , the beanbag that gets colored if you hover the first circle fits perfectly until you increase the browser width or make the browser window smaller. Is it possible to scale the height and width of the image so it always fits perfect? The location already scales with it correctly.

Comment: aha ok thx. And yes this is easy to solve you only need to multiply `scaleX and scaleY` with `scaleToWidth` and it should fit perfectly. but the other tooltips seems wrong somehow which contained a dog :)

Comment: Friend what about the bounty?

Comment: I forgot, I gave you the bounty now!